# Return address in ListView

Tags: django, listview, django-templates, django-context

How to return address in `DealershipList` with ListView?

I try in views.py

```
class DealershipList(ListView):
    template_name = 'dealership_list.html'
    model = Dealership

    def get_queryset(self):
        pass

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DealershipList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        address = Dealership.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['address'])
        context['address'] = self.address
        return context
```

I need in templates.

```
{% for dealership in dealership_list %}
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h4>{{ dealership.dealership }}</h4>
        <p>{{ address.address }}</p>
        <p>Site: <a href="{{ dealership.site }}" target="_blank">{{ dealership.site }}</a></p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Address:

Av. One, 2

Dealership:

dealership name

Av. One, 2

models.py

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(_(u'endereço'), max_length=80)
    address_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(_(u'número'))
    district = models.CharField(_('bairro'), max_length=80)
    city = models.CharField(_('cidade'), max_length=80)

class Dealership(models.Model):
    dealership = models.CharField(_(u'concessionária'), max_length=50)
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        "Address", verbose_name=u'endereço', related_name='dealership_address')
    site = models.CharField(_('site'), max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now i try:

```
class DealershipList(ListView):
    template_name = 'core/dealership/dealership_list.html'
    model = Dealership

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        id_address = Address.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        address = Dealership.objects.filter(address=id_address)
        context = super(DealershipList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['address'] = address
        return context
```

**But not work**

urls.py

```
url(r'^dealerships/$', DealershipList.as_view(), name='dealership_list'),
```

Comment: Could you explain better what do you want to acomplish and what steps did you do to acomplish it? Also can you show your urls.py?

Comment: i need return Dealership and Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

```
{{ dealership.address.address }}
```